# Is there a most efficient way to read/write upto 10GB binary file in C#?

Tags: c#, io

We have a project where we need to migrate up to 10GB of binary files. The steps are 
1) read file by message size
2) do some processing
3) either write the original message or processed message back to a new binary file.

for a 10GB file, after processing it becomes 14GB. Currently it takes nearly 2 hours.

I am wondering if I can do some IO trick to trim that time down.

```
using (FileStream fsInput =new FileStream(inputfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (FileStream fsOutput = File.Create(outputfilename))
            {
                long total = fsInput.Length;
                long progress = 0;

                unsafe
                {
                    int hdrSize = sizeof(FullMessageHeader);
                    byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[hdrSize];

                    while (fsInput.Position < fsInput.Length)
                    {                         
                        progress += fsInput.Read(headerBuffer, 0, hdrSize);
                        int msgSize = 0;
                        fixed (byte* hdr = headerBuffer)
                        {
                            msgSize = *(int*)(hdr + MessageHeaderOffsets.Size);
                        }

                        byte[] msg = new byte[msgSize];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(headerBuffer, 0, msg, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
                        fsInput.Position -= hdrSize;
                        progress += fsInput.Read(msg, 0, msgSize);

                        fixed (byte* ptr = msg)
                        {
                            byte[] ba = ProcessMessage(ptr);
                            if (ba.Length == 0)
                            {
                                fsOutput.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fsOutput.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could certainly avoid creating that buffer everytime `byte[] msg = new byte[msgSize];`. Apart from that, I don't think so.

Comment: I have a code which I tried and I didn't get much improvement

Comment: I didn't say that it was much. I couldn't, given that you practically did not provide any information besides the code and just hope that complete strangers guess your context and solve all your problems for free.

Answer (score 0):

so finally as suggested by Georg, and some clean up of the above code, I was able to reduce the time from 2 hours to 10 minutes which is not the most optimum but acceptable.

```
        Dictionary<int, byte[]> byteDictionary = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
        using (FileStream fsInput =new FileStream(inputfilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (FileStream fsOutput = File.Create(outputfilename))
            {
                long total = fsInput.Length;
                long progress = 0;

                unsafe
                {
                    int hdrSize = sizeof(FullMessageHeader);
                    byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[hdrSize];

                    while (fsInput.Position < fsInput.Length)
                    {                         
                        progress += fsInput.Read(headerBuffer, 0, hdrSize);
                        int msgSize = 0;
                        fixed (byte* hdr = headerBuffer)
                        {
                            msgSize = *(int*)(hdr + MessageHeaderOffsets.Size);
                        }

                        byte[] msg = byteDictionary.ContainsKey(msgSize)
                            ? byteDictionary[msgSize]
                            : new byte[msgSize];
                        if (!byteDictionary.ContainsKey(msgSize))
                        {
                            byteDictionary[msgSize] = msg;
                        }
                        //byte[] msg = new byte[msgSize];
                        //Buffer.BlockCopy(headerBuffer, 0, msg, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
                        fsInput.Position -= hdrSize;
                        progress += fsInput.Read(msg, 0, msgSize);

                        fixed (byte* ptr = msg)
                        {
                            //fsOutput.Write(msg,0,msg.Length);
                            byte[] ba = ProcessMessage(ptr);
                            if (ba.Length == 0)
                            {
                                fsOutput.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fsOutput.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```